# keep the review filter while switching between review tabs

Tags: feature-request, review-queues

I was reviewing [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) close votes. I switched to the stats tab to see how many reviews I've completed so far, and then came back to the review tab and continued reviewing - to find myself skipping almost everything. Then I realized that due to the switch between tabs, the review filter got reset, and I'm in the common review queue.

Is it possible to keep the review filters while just switching between the review tabs..?